# Trying to rewrite mysql_* to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all I should say that I started to learn PDO and trying to rewrite some old mine codes. Here is one that I found on tutorial for a jquery/ajax/pdo/mysql comment system which is working.
This is the `mysql_*` part which I'm trying to rewrite -> file `submit.php` which submits the comments to database.

```
$arr = array();
$validates = Comment::validate($arr);

if($validates)
{
   /* Everything is OK, insert to database: */

   mysql_query("    INSERT INTO comments(name,url,email,body)
                VALUES (
                    '".$arr['name']."',
                    '".$arr['url']."',
                    '".$arr['email']."',
                    '".$arr['body']."'
                )");

  $arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
  $arr['id'] = mysql_insert_id();

  $arr = array_map('stripslashes',$arr);

  $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);

  /* Outputting the markup of the just-inserted comment: */

  echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));

}
else
{
    /* Outputtng the error messages */
    echo '{"status":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
}
```

Here is my try of this piece of code.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$arr = array();
$validates = Comment::validate($arr);

if($validates)
{
     /* Everything is OK, insert to database: */
     $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comments ( name,url,email,body ) 
                            VALUES (:name, :url, :email, :body)");

                        $sql->execute(array(
                        ':name'     => $name,
                        ':url'          => $url,
                        ':email'    => $email,
                        ':body'     => $body

                        ));
     $arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
     $arr['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();

     $arr = array_map('stripslashes',$arr);

     $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);

     /* Outputting the markup of the just-inserted comment: */

     echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));

}
else
{
    /* Outputtng the error messages */
    echo '{"status":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
}
```

When I hit button `Submit` just nothing happen. Didn't insert anything into database. And the button become inactive.

If need I can show javascript part or the form as well. Thank's

UPDATE: This is the comment.class.php which is included also into the submit.php

```
class Comment
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {   
       /*
       /    The constructor
       */

       $this->data = $row;
    }

    public function markup()
    {
       // this just output the comment on page nothing special some html
    }

    public static function validate(&$arr)
    {

       $errors = array();
       $data    = array();

       // Using the filter_input function introduced in PHP 5.2.0

       if(!($data['email'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
       {
            $errors['email'] = 'Wrong email.';
       }

       if(!($data['url'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'url',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)))
       {
            // If the URL field was not populated with a valid URL,
            // act as if no URL was entered at all:

            $url = '';
       }

    // Using the filter with a custom callback function:

       if(!($data['body'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'body',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
       {
           $errors['body'] = 'Please enter your comment.';
       }

       if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
       {
           $errors['name'] = 'Please enter your name.';
       }

       if(!empty($errors)){

        // If there are errors, copy the $errors array to $arr:

        $arr = $errors;
        return false;
       }  

       // If the data is valid, sanitize all the data and copy it to $arr:

       foreach($data as $k=>$v){
           $arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
       }

       $arr['email'] = strtolower(trim($arr['email']));

       return true;     
    } 

   private static function validate_text($str)
   {

      if(mb_strlen($str,'utf8')<1)
        return false;           

      $str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str));

      // Remove the new line characters that are left
      $str = str_replace(array(chr(10),chr(13)),'',$str);

      return $str;
   }
}
```

Comment: you're mixing `mysql_` in with PDO; *why?*

Comment: why is this ^ comment being ignored? don't ask yourself why your code's failing. voted to close. Plus, we don't even know if you're using PDO to connect with in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, was away from PC. @Fred-ii-, did you mean the `comment.class? Also as I mentioned I just started to try to rewrite them and still it is not clear how to rewrite all of it but I'm trying.

Comment: `$arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);` why is that in there? you can't mix that with PDO. When using any kind of MySQL API, you must use the same API from connection to query. There must not be any instances of `mysql_` used anywhere.

Comment: So the problem _may be_ is in this mixing both api's.

Comment: it is playing a rather large role; yes.

Comment: As I read in PDO there is no equivalent of  `mysql_real_escape_string` so instead I can just use `$arr[$k] = $v;`. Am I right?

Comment: they've replaced those with "binding"/prepared statements. so, go ahead and give it a whirl

Comment: As I replaced them in query `$sql->execute(array( ':name'     => $name, ':url'  => $url,...`.

Comment: Thank's @Fred-ii- for the comments. I will read and try other things till I learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the source of the array `$arr = array();`, but it is assigned to null before the insert query. So it means, literally you are inserting nothing into the database. So check your array well, maybe it was to be like

`$arr = array('name'=>'My Name', 'url'=>'url', 'email'=>'my email', 'body'=>'comment');`

And if there is nothing wrong with your array then I think you are missing the keys of the array. You can either store the array values into variables or use them straight away. So use ,

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$arr = array();
$validates = Comment::validate($arr);

if($validates)
{
 /* Everything is OK, insert to database: */
 $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comments ( name,url,email,body ) 
                        VALUES (:name, :url, :email, :body)");

                    $sql->execute(array(
                    ':name'     => $arr['name'],
                    ':url'      => $arr['url'],
                    ':email'    => $arr['email'],
                    ':body'     => $arr['body']

                    ));
 $arr['dt'] = date('r',time());
 $arr['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();

 $arr = array_map('stripslashes',$arr);

 $insertedComment = new Comment($arr);

 /* Outputting the markup of the just-inserted comment: */

 echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));

}
else
{
/* Outputtng the error messages */
echo '{"status":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: sometimes using just `name` as a column can cause SQL errors. Because `name` is a SQL keyword, so try placing only the name in those back ticks.

Comment: Thank's for the answer but the result is same. Doesn't insert into database. Note: with the mysql_* code is working fine so I don't think the problem is in the `name`.

Comment: I don't know but the fact is from your codes array `$arr` is empty. So check it.

Comment: I have added `$arr` like in your code. Also added into my question `comment.class`. May be the problem is something in there.

Comment: @Stan you array `$arr` is empty, so please check that one. It needs to be an associative array with name, email and the others as keys which have specific values. So feed the array with those values.

Comment: You mean like you show- `':name'     => $arr['name'],` .. and so on? Also I've change the field from `name` to `comment_name` regarding of what you said. Still when I press submit I got `Working,...` and that's it..

Comment: @GideonAppoh, In the `comment.class.php` doesn't `$data = array();` populate the array? I mean for example `filter_input(INPUT_POST,'body',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text')))` and so on?

Comment: So what are the elements of the $data array which from your class gets its values from $row.

Comment: What I can understand from the comments with this tutorial `$data` hold and populates the $arr array passed as a paremter. I've mentioned that this is whole comment system didn't wrote by me but I've trying to rewrite it. So as I can understand when I press button `submit` it's send data to submit.php via AJAX and comment.class.php. Comment.class check for the errors and true inputs and submit.php insert into the database.

Comment: Seems it will be a little longer than I think to rewrite this script. I need to read more and understand it well. Thank's for the help. If I have further questions I'll start new topic.

Comment: Yh, I also try to understand OOP concept very well because your class was a bit complicated.